# PSfile Close Opened Shared PDF's - REGEX

Tags: regex, command

Description of what is wanted:
Close ALL OPENED SHARED PDF files (so that file can be overwritten)

After many tries with OPENFILES and NET FILE, I have come to finally using PSFILE to query and close opened PDF files however because PSFILE reports the open file ID  INSIDE brackets ... the command to close the file will not complete because of the brackets.

Please excuse my copied and pasted code below...I am learning so I am unsure what the Findstr command below (the regex part) is actually doing but it does seem to find all opened PDF's

EXAMPLE:

```
for /F %a in ('psfile \\servername ^|findstr /i "\\.*\.pdf"') do psfile \\servername %a /c
```

The result of the code above will find the opened PDF's. 
PSFILE displays the results in this format:
**NOTICE THE Brackets around the ID**

```
[2214593372] D:\PATH TO\FILE.PDF
User:   USERNAME
Locks:  0
Access: Read
```

Because of the Brackets around the ID number the final part of the code:

```
do psfile \\servername %a /c
```

Reports - **NOTICE the BRACKETS**

```
psfile \\wgdfp01 [2214593372] /c
```

Which then reports failure:

```
No files opened remotely on SERVERNAME.
```

Can anyone please help me out... If I could get it to not report the brackets...then the last part of the code should work?

{EDIT}
The response will always be [NNNNNNNNNNN] N= 0-9
I just need it to ONLY PASS the numbers within the brackets to the command.
I will not bore you with the different combinations I have tried for regex. 
But when I add something to the ^|   it will reply with  |  not expected at this time.

THANK YOU

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fix the issue.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /f %%A IN ('psfile \\SERVERNAME ^| findstr /i "\\.*\.pdf"') DO call:CallFunction %%A

GOTO Exit

:CallFunction
SET foo=%~1
SET foo=%foo:[=%
SET foo=%foo:]=%
psfile \\SERVERNAME %foo% /c

:Exit
```